# right() function not working without using rtrim. only working like this :right(rtrim(column_name),value) WHY?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't understand why the `right()` function won't work without `rtrim`.
I even used `update` to get `rtrim` for entire column but still `right()` wont work without using `Rtrim()` inside it.

I made a table in SQL Server 2008. The table has only one column `name char(30)`.
I tried to get a substring counting from right side using the `right()` function.
The result shows just blank column.
When I try using `left()` function to get substring from left side it works as expected but `right()` function doesn't work without using `RTRIM`.

THIS WILL WORK

```sql
select right(rtrim(name),5) from emp
```

THIS WONT WORK

```sql
select right(name,5) from emp
```

I expect to get substring of last 3 characters in name column.
My result shows an empty column

Comment: You realise that `char(30)` is padded with spaces to 30 characters, and that is what your `right` returns?

Comment: May be your data having space at end of the string

Comment: Use NVARCHAR(30) in place of CHAR(30). This will solve your issue. As CHAR(30) will always assign spaces after your original value. Now if your value is 'abc' actually it is abc and 27 trailing spaces in it and as a result you are getting blank or spaces with RIGHT.

Comment: select your data without any conversion or any function. Copy those data in NotePad++ and check how many extra characters after your required string using "Show ALL Characters" tool View > Show Symbol > Show ALL Characters. You will identify that why RIGHT() not working.

Comment: thank you guys. my result was showing black column which in fact was just empty spaces from the right side. SO DOES that mean when i do Rtrim using update it will not save the changes  to the table?

Comment: Using the `char` data type is almost always an error. It has absolutely no advantages over `varchar`  (or `nvarchar`) but many annoying disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

`char(5)` is a fixed-length type so the value includes trailing spaces in cases where the value is less than the specified max size. When you use `RIGHT`, the trailing spaces are returned:

```
DECLARE @name char(30) = 'abcdef';
SELECT RIGHT(@name,5); --returns 5 spaces
```

Using `TRIM`, the trailing spaces are removed and the returned data type is `varchar(5)`:

```
SELECT RIGHT(RTRIM(@name),5); --returns 'bcdef'
```

You should probably use `varchar(30)` instead of `char(30)` for a Name column because the data will vary and length and you probably don't want to store the unneeded spaces in the database. `char` is most appropriate when the actual values are the same size.

Comment: You meant "trailing spaces", not "training spaces" in first line :)